# How can I use Perl to record MP3 files on Windows?

Tags: perl, mp3, cpan

Is there any Perl module for recording mp3 files specially on Win32?
If yes could someone provide an example.

Comment: What is the source of the audio?

Comment: Do you mean you want to **convert** WMA or WAV files to MP3?

Comment: I want to record voice on Win32 to MP3 also to convert WAV files  format to MP3 format

Comment: Instead of burying your clarification in a comment, edit your question :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Win32::SoundRec](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::SoundRec) to record to WAV format. You can use [lame](http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/%2acheckout%2a/lame/lame/USAGE) to encode WAV to MP3.